# GetNNodes and GetTotalNodes SCIP

Tags: python, nodes, scip

So I'm using the SCIP python package for B&B optimization. And I recently encountered the GetNNodes for a problem and GetTotalNodes and can't really decipher the difference from the documentation.
The problem im solving contains at least 200 variables and from the getNNodes I can get values like 400, which of course is not reasonable in terms of the scope of the problem, right?

So im wondering should I just use get total nodes and what is the difference?

Comment: For the community to better answer your question please add snippet of the code, where you need help and give any example set to make to more clear

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For reference consider the article: 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.01629.pdf,
There is associate code, but my question still stands.

Answer (score 0):

`getNNodes` will return the number of nodes in the current run, while `getNTotalNodes` will return the number of nodes in total (which includes nodes from restarts for example).

Why would 400 nodes be unreasonable if you have 200 variables? The branch and bound algorithm needs (in the worst case) an exponential number of nodes.

Edit: Your question actually seems to go more in the direction "how come LP based branch-and-bound can sometimes require a low number of nodes"? Best case, you need only one node. Your LP solution might be completely integer (in some cases this can even be guaranteed, for example, if your constraint matrix is totally unimodular). While this very rarely happens, the solver uses a lot of techniques to branch in such a fashion that the number of nodes is very low (if you are interested I would suggest looking up strongbranching). Then a plethora of different cutting planes are separated to strenghten the relaxation and decrease the number of nodes. All this to say:

- the worst case very rarely happens and branch-and-bound usually does not need an exponential number of nodes
- a lot of work went into enuring that the number of nodes is low

Comment: What exactly do you mean by restarts?

well Realistically in a branch and bound you would need to consider a plethora of different combinations (with their LP relaxed bound) To assert that your solution indeed is the global optima. I dont see how that can be the case with so few nodes.

Comment: For reference I'm reading the article from 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.01629.pdf
Where they get fewer nodes than variables even which seem quite unreasonable, hence I was wondering what the interpretation of the getNNodes exactly is.

Comment: I edited my original answer. restarts happen when the tree is estimated to be large and so the solve is restarted with a different strategy.

Comment: Thanks that clarified a bit more as to my question.
And yes I think ur rephrasing of my question is appropriate. Why I asked this is that on solving roughly 100 MIPS with 400 variables my mean number of nodes was only 600 which I thought was dauntingly small. But perhaps it is not so odd after all. (I'm comparing different branching strategies right now).
It still boggles my mind that the bounds we find can ensure that so few nodes would need to be considered but perhaps that is just something I'll need to accept.
As a last thing, could you potentially expand on the cutting planes?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That is a huge topic, and I suggest you research it yourself if interested. This is a good talk about the topic to get you started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Bdhd40U1Bc